Minio file upload freeze for files larger than 100MB with nginx on raspberry pi
I have tried a lot of different options for nginx that I have found in similar questions, but they haven't helped me:
upstream minio_s3 {
   least_conn;
   server minio.localhost:9010;
}
upstream minio_console {
   least_conn;
   server minio.localhost:9011;
}



server {
  server_name example.com;

   # Allow special characters in headers
   ignore_invalid_headers off;
   # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
   # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
   client_max_body_size 0;
   # Disable buffering
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_request_buffering off;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      chunked_transfer_encoding off;

      proxy_pass http://minio_s3; # This uses the upstream directive definition to load balance
   }

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  listen 443 ssl;
}

server {
  server_name example.com;

   # Allow special characters in headers
   ignore_invalid_headers off;
   # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
   # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
   client_max_body_size 16384M;
   # Disable buffering
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_request_buffering off;
   proxy_connect_timeout 30m;
   proxy_read_timeout 30m;
   proxy_send_timeout 30m;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 999999;
   client_body_timeout 30m;
   client_body_temp_path /home/example/tmp;
   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_connect_timeout 999999;
      proxy_read_timeout 30m; # Default value is 60s which is not sufficient for MinIO.
      proxy_send_timeout 30m; # Default value is 60s which is not sufficient for MinIO.
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      send_timeout 30m;
      # This is necessary to pass the correct IP to be hashed
      real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

      # To support websocket
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
      chunked_transfer_encoding off;
      tcp_nodelay on;

      proxy_pass http://minio_console/;

   }

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  listen 443 ssl;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot]

    server_name example.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

I run minio with docker compose:
minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: server --address ":${MINIO_API_PORT-9010}" --console-address ":${MINIO_PORT-9011}" /data
    ports:
      - '${MINIO_API_PORT-9010}:${MINIO_API_PORT-9010}'
      - '${MINIO_PORT-9011}:${MINIO_PORT-9011}'
    volumes:
      - './minio_data:/data'
    environment:
      - 'MINIO_ROOT_USER=${MINIO_ROOT_USER-username}'
      - 'MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD-password}'
      - 'MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=${MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS-avatars,apps}'
      - 'MINIO_SERVER_URL=${MINIO_SERVER_URL-http://minio.localhost:9010}'
      - 'MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL=${MINIO_URL-http://minio.localhost:9011}'

mc admin config export minio:
subnet license= api_key= proxy= 
# callhome enable=off frequency=24h 
drive max_timeout=15m 
site name= region= 
api requests_max=1600 requests_deadline=15m cluster_deadline=15m cors_allow_origin=* remote_transport_deadline=2h list_quorum=strict replication_priority=auto replication_max_workers=500 transition_workers=100 stale_uploads_cleanup_interval=6h stale_uploads_expiry=24h delete_cleanup_interval=5m odirect=on gzip_objects=on root_access=on sync_events=off object_max_versions=9223372036854775807 
scanner speed=default alert_excess_versions=100 alert_excess_folders=50000 
batch replication_workers_wait=0ms keyrotation_workers_wait=0ms expiration_workers_wait=0ms 
compression allow_encryption=off extensions=.txt,.log,.csv,.json,.tar,.xml,.bin mime_types=text/*,application/json,application/xml,binary/octet-stream,*,application/x-executable 
# identity_openid enable= display_name= config_url= client_id= client_secret= claim_name=policy claim_userinfo= role_policy= claim_prefix= redirect_uri= redirect_uri_dynamic=off scopes= vendor= keycloak_realm= keycloak_admin_url= 
# identity_ldap enable= server_addr= srv_record_name= user_dn_search_base_dn= user_dn_search_filter= user_dn_attributes= group_search_filter= group_search_base_dn= tls_skip_verify=off server_insecure=off server_starttls=off lookup_bind_dn= lookup_bind_password= 
# identity_tls skip_verify=off 
# identity_plugin url= auth_token= role_policy= role_id= 
# policy_plugin url= auth_token= enable_http2=off 
# logger_webhook enable=off endpoint= auth_token= client_cert= client_key= proxy= batch_size=1 queue_size=100000 queue_dir= 
# audit_webhook enable=off endpoint= auth_token= client_cert= client_key= batch_size=1 queue_size=100000 queue_dir= 
# audit_kafka enable=off topic= brokers= sasl_username= sasl_password= sasl_mechanism=plain client_tls_cert= client_tls_key= tls_client_auth=0 sasl=off tls=off tls_skip_verify=off version= queue_size=100000 queue_dir= 
# notify_webhook enable=off endpoint= auth_token= queue_limit=0 queue_dir= client_cert= client_key= 
# notify_amqp enable=off url= exchange= exchange_type= routing_key= mandatory=off durable=off no_wait=off internal=off auto_deleted=off delivery_mode=0 publisher_confirms=off queue_limit=0 queue_dir= 
# notify_kafka enable=off topic= brokers= sasl_username= sasl_password= sasl_mechanism=plain client_tls_cert= client_tls_key= tls_client_auth=0 sasl=off tls=off tls_skip_verify=off queue_limit=0 queue_dir= version= batch_size=0 compression_codec= compression_level= 
# notify_mqtt enable=off broker= topic= password= username= qos=0 keep_alive_interval=0s reconnect_interval=0s queue_dir= queue_limit=0 
# notify_nats enable=off address= subject= username= password= token= tls=off tls_skip_verify=off cert_authority= client_cert= client_key= ping_interval=0 jetstream=off streaming=off streaming_async=off streaming_max_pub_acks_in_flight=0 streaming_cluster_id= queue_dir= queue_limit=0 
# notify_nsq enable=off nsqd_address= topic= tls=off tls_skip_verify=off queue_dir= queue_limit=0 
# notify_mysql enable=off format=namespace dsn_string= table= queue_dir= queue_limit=0 max_open_connections=2 
# notify_postgres enable=off format=namespace connection_string= table= queue_dir= queue_limit=0 max_open_connections=2 
# notify_elasticsearch enable=off url= format=namespace index= queue_dir= queue_limit=0 username= password= 
# notify_redis enable=off format=namespace address= key= password= user= queue_dir= queue_limit=0 
# lambda_webhook enable=off endpoint= auth_token= client_cert= client_key= 
# etcd endpoints= path_prefix= coredns_path=/skydns client_cert= client_cert_key= 
# cache enable=off endpoint= block_size= 
browser csp_policy="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com;  connect-src 'self' https://unpkg.com;" hsts_seconds=0 hsts_include_subdomains=off hsts_preload=off referrer_policy=strict-origin-when-cross-origin 
ilm transition_workers=100 expiration_workers=100

mc --debug admin trace minio:
mc: <DEBUG> GET /minio/admin/v3/trace?batch-expire=false&batch-keyrotation=false&batch-replication=false&bootstrap=false&decommission=false&err=false&ftp=false&healing=false&ilm=false&internal=false&os=false&rebalance=false&replication-resync=false&s3=true&scanner=false&storage=false&threshold=0s HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9010
User-Agent: MinIO (linux; arm64) madmin-go/2.0.0 mc/RELEASE.2024-07-03T20-17-25Z
Accept-Encoding: zstd,gzip
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=Sha256/20240709//s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=**REDACTED**
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: Sha256
X-Amz-Date: 20240709T063437Z

mc: <DEBUG> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2024 06:34:38 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Accel-Buffering: no
X-Amz-Id-2: ID
X-Amz-Request-Id: ID
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

mc: <DEBUG> Response Time: 1.005568677s

2024-07-09T06:35:10.763 [200 OK] s3.GetBucketLocation mt-minio.drewdru.com/games/?location=  89.232.40.222,89.232.40.222              1.281ms      ⇣  1.252028ms  ↑ 215 B ↓ 128 B

On minio console I upload file and after this log it freezes between 3%-10%
If I try to upload directly to minio without nginx by IP and port than request immediately fail with an error Error: A network error occurred. (in Firefox) or Error: Error - File size too large (in Google Chrome).
I set up my raspberry pi to boot from SSD and I allocated a large swap, so it should be enough to upload large files.
